# Basic PDF handling in iOS

Tags: ios, pdf

How would I implement basic PDF handling like page addition, removal, rotation, and moving (move page 1 to page 3...) in an iOS application?  I've found some third party libraries online but their focus seems to either raw creation or just viewing features (searching, annotations).

Comment: All I've ever managed is creation, emailing, and printing.

Comment: How familiar are you with PDF internals? Moving and deleting pages is fairly trivial, as is rotation (manipulate basic `/Page` and `/Pages` objects). As for adding pages .. are you writing a full page design program, or would you just add blank pages?